# Give a closed plane curve C with k (curvature) > 0 that is not convex, Draw closed plane curves with rotation indices 0, 2, -2, and 3

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, plane-curves, curves

1.) Give a closed plane curve C with k (curvature) > 0 that is not convex.

**can someone please explain these concepts to me. How can you have a closed plane curve like this? Do you used signed curvature?**

2.) Draw closed plane curves with rotation indices 0, 2, -2, and 3, respectively.

**I am unsure about the rotation indices, would you just plot the points 0,2,-2,3 and draw a curve that curves around those points? Could someone show me a plot of such and explain the concept to me?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that the curve will need to have self-intersections. (A *simple* closed curve of positive curvature must be convex). Here's an inspirational example:

[image: positive curvature]

The parametric equations of the above curve are 
$$
x=3\cos(-t)+\cos5 t,\qquad y = 3\sin(-t)+\sin 5t
$$

Imagine a planet orbiting the origin clockwise, and its moon orbiting the planet counterclockwise. That's the trajectory of the moon.

> Would you just plot the points $0,2,-2,3$

No, not at all. You need four different curves, one for each index. One that goes around the origin $0$ times, one that goes $2$ times, one that goes $-2$ times (negative means clockwise direction, positive is counterclockwise)...

For example, you could make the planet rotate twice as fast around the sun, or three times as fast... Try playing with coefficients of $t$ in the above formula, using for exmaple [Function Plotter](https://functionplotter.com/).

Comment: Thank You! I understand the first question now, but I still don't see how you could draw a closed plane curves with rotation indices 0, 2, -2, and 3. I am still slightly confused. Could you provide just a little more explanation or possibly a drawing of how I could possibly do this? Thank you!

Comment: To have $0$, draw a circle that does not go around the origin at all. Like something centered at $(2,0)$ with radius $1$. To have $2$, just go around the circle twice: $x=\cos 2t$, $y=\sin 2t$, $0\le t\le 2\pi$. Same for other winding numbers.

Comment: Ok so for clarification my drawing would have a circle centered at say (2,0) with radius 1 which does not go around the origin, the I would have a circle with equations x=cos2t, y=sin2t from 0 to 2pi for indice 2.
and for -2 just have negative of the above
And for indice 3 have like x=cos3t, y=sin3t
And just plot all of these on one graph?

Comment: @Unkle The problem did not ask you to plot all of the on one graph. Separate graphs would be a better illustration; less messy. Also, while the parametric equations correctly give the desired winding number, the visualization will be unsatisfactory: the curve just goes over the same points twice or thrice. To improve visualization, you can throw in another small trigonometric term that does not change the winding number. [Like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3Dcos%282t%29%2B0.5cos%28t%29%2C+y%3Dsin%282t%29%2B0.5sin%28t%29)

Comment: so like another cos or sin;
Like for indice 3: x=cos3t + sin2t, y=sin3t + cost? Would that work?

Comment: Here were my graphs can you please let me know if these would be correct graphs? 
indice 0: (x-2)^2 + y^2 = 1
indice 2: x=cos2t, y=sin2t
indice -2: x=-cos2t, y=-sin2t
indice 3: x=cos(3t+1), y=sin(3t-1)
all 0<= t <= 2pi
Thanks!

Comment: @Unkle If you add another trig wave of same magnitude, there's a risk that they cancel and the curve passes through the origin. The winding number is not even defined in such a case. This is why I added a small term.

Comment: sorry for asking again but I am not sure where to add the small term, do you mean like a +1 inside the cos or sin?
Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @Unkle If you followed the link "Like this" in my comment, you would see a complete solution for index $2$. For other indices, just replace $2t$ by $-2t$ or $3t$, etc.

Comment: Oh ok, so for indice 3 we could have x=cos3t, y=sin3t where  0 <= t <= 2pi, so this would generate a circle around the origin that would circle around it 3 times in the counterclockwise direction from 0 to 2pi 3 times
@thursday